# What happened to Noah and Allie at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-notebook

At the end of *The Notebook*, we see Allie and Noah dead together holding each other's hands. I think that Noah had been trying for a couple of times to let Allie remember everything permanently. But the expected "miracle" did not happen a single time, and every time she lost everything. Now my question is how did they die together? As this was not the first time Allie forgot everything, I don't believe it was a serious physical problem that can cause death. Apparently, Noah was also not sick, although he got a heart attack. But I believe it was out of his sorrow for again losing her. He was there to help Allie. So how come they died together? Did they commit suicide?

Comment: from what i can recall, no.  but it's been too long to give a good answer.  but still, my instincts/memories say no.

Comment: But then how could they die at the same time being not seriously ill?

Comment: @Mistu4u Because Nicholas Sparks.

Comment: @TylerShads, What do you wanna say? :o

Comment: No, thats the reason.  He is famous for writing chick novels that typically have the same premise and always has kooky things to symbolize eternal love like 'dying together suddenly' in a deus ex machina fashion

Answer (score 4):

There is no mention of them committing suicide. The whole premise of the end of the film is that Allie remembered everything and that she and Noah died together at the same time because their love was so strong.

Answer (score 2):

Allie asks Noah if he thinks their love is so strong that it can grant miracles and he says yes, which is proven by her memory returning against all odds. She then asks if their love is so strong that it could take them away together, which would be another miracle. Their dying in the next scene shows that their love was so strong that it granted the miracle of them dying together. They didn't commit suicide and there was no medical problem, it was just a miracle. It's a really cheesy plotline, but that's what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

No, they didn't commit suicide. They just died together. In a scene before that, Allie askes Noah if their love has the power to grant miracles, and Noah tells her yes. She also asks him if their love can take them away together (die together). So they just wanted to imply that their love was so strong that they died together. 
Although, in the original novel, on which the movie is based, only Allie dies and Noah continues to live at the nursing home. It also has a sequel called "The Wedding".

Answer (score 0):

I do think that suicide is implied at the end. There is Allie's question to Noah if they can die together and his answer is that he believes they can do whatever they want to do...so just like Romeo and Juliet...

Answer (score 0):

People can die from a broken heart.Aldo from experience working in a care home towards the end people can brief come back as they realise their dying but the film exaggerates this to make its point

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Actually only allie dies if you read the sequel. Noah lives on into the second book. He helps his son in law recapture the spark in his marriage while they plan their own daughter's wedding

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! The downvotes are because you appear to be talking about the novels, while the question is about the film adaptation. Film adaptations of novels always change things, so just because he eventually survived in the novels, that doesn't mean he survived in the film.